# Problemas con JavaFX en NetBeans

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-11

Uso NetBeans, y estoy iniciándome en **JavaFX**, pero cuando intento crear un proyecto ***"Aplicación FX"*** me sale el siguiente error:

> **Failed to automatically set-up a JavaFX Platform.**
>   Please go to Platform Manager, create a non-default
>   Java SE platform, then go to the JavaFX tab, enable JavaFX and fill in the paths to valid JavaFX SDK and JavaFX Runtime. Note: JavaFX SDK can be downloaded from JavaFX website.

Esto es lo que he instalado hasta ahora:

- NetBeans 11
- JDK 12

Tenía entendido que las funciones necesarias para usar JavaFX ya estaban incluidas en el JDK 12, o aún me falta algo?
¿Podrían ser las versiones que tengo instaladas el problema?

Buenos días, y muchas gracias por el tiempo que se toman para contestar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A partir de Java 11](https://www.muylinux.com/2018/09/20/javafx-11-modulo-independiente-jdk/) viene por separado.

La buena noticia es que puedes descargar el SDK de Open JavaFx gratuitamente desde [su sitio oficial](https://openjfx.io/) ya que es opensource y está licenciado bajo GPL.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Tenías razón.
Ya lo descargue, ahora solo me falta agregar los archivos a NetBeans, cierto?
Disculpa, podrías orientarme en esto?

Comment: Lo agregas a tu path y Netbeans lo detecta automáticamente

Comment: Ya agregué la ruta de la carpeta bin que pertenece a javafx, a la variable path, pero aún así, cuando intento crear el proyecto me aparecen errores,
Si gustas darte una vuelta por la segunda parte de la pregunta, sería de mucha ayuda:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/272542/cómo-importar-javafx-en-netbeans

Answer (score -1):

Después de la versión **JDK 8**, el **JDK** (que ahora es **OpenJDK**) no trae soporte para **JavaFx**, pero si es posible crear aplicaciones **JavaFx** agregando el ***SDK OpenJFX*** descargandolo desde [su web](https://openjfx.io/).
Las instrucciones son un tanto largas, aquí hay una buena explicación en [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bk42DbVBzXM).