# Cómo importar JavaFX en NetBeans

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-11

Quiero crear un proyecto de **JavaFX en NetBeans**, ya tengo descargado lo siguiente:

- NetBeans 11
- JDK 12
- SDK de Open JavaFx 11

Con ayuda me enteré de que había que configurar la variable de entorno *path*, agregando:

- **La dirección de la carpeta bin del JDK.** Desconozco para qué exactamente.
- **La dirección de la carpeta bin del SDK.** Tengo entendido que de esta forma se *"importan"* los archivos del **SDK JavaFX** para que NetBeans los reconozco automáticamente.

Sin embargo, a la hora de querer crear el proyecto de JavaFX, me sigue apareciendo el siguiente error y no me deja crear el proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe destacar que es un proyecto que intento crear desde la categoría **Java con Ant**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También intenté crear uno desde la categoría **Java con Maven** y sí me permite crear el proyecto, pero con el siguiente error a la hora de importar la biblioteca:

> package javafx.application does not exist

Aquí les dejo una imagen más:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado, al crear un **proyecto con Gradle**, no aparece la opción de aplicación JavaFX, dejo captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Podrían ayudarme a saber qué estoy haciendo mal, o si me falta algo? Se los agradecería mucho. Si requieren más información pueden decirme.
¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Tienes tu JavaFX Scene Builder instalado?

Comment: Para el caso de Maven agrega [la dependencia](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx/11), si los jars de tu instalación de tu JavaFX están en el classpath puedes incluso ponerla provided en vez de compile para no incluirlos en tu binario para distribución

Comment: Sí, descargué tanto Scene Buider como JavaFX de la pagina de Gluon.
No estoy muy familiarizado con todo esto, podrías indicarme los pasos  que tengo que seguir para poder agregar la dependencia?

Comment: Por favor desde consola obten la ruta de JavaFX,  tu PATH y tu classpath y arégalos a la pregunta, tal vez nos ayude a determinar por qué no tienes los jars en el classpath.

Comment: @OscarHrdz si lo creas con Gradle o Maven tienes el mismo problema?

Comment: @Elenasys no aparece la opción para crear el proyecto JavaFX, adjunté una imagen a la descripción.
Gracias de nuevo por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

**Solución con MAVEN y GLUON plugin en NETBEANS 12++**

Hay que tener le plugin de Gluon para Netbeans . Está disponible en la lista de plugins del propio ide

[image: gluon plugin netbeans]

Una vez instalado , reiniciamos y creamos un nuevo proyecto. Ahora también está disponible la opción de gluon , pero eso es para crear apps de javafx para móviles . Utilizamos las que el plugin de gluon creo en la carpeta de Maven . Una es una plantilla para empezar usando .fxml y la otra es javafx con clases de java sin .fxml . En este caso`FXML javafx maven archetype (gluon)`

[image: elegir javafx maven]

si los valores de las versiones de los plugins  de javafx y maven están desactualizados hay que cambiarlos

[image: elegir valores javafx maven]

a valores más recientes `key javafx-version , value 17.0.2` y`key javafx-maven-plugin-version , value 0.0.8`

[image: version más reciente javafx]

Una vez creada la plantilla está lista para compilarse ya que maven ha descargado las dependencias
[image: asdsd]