# JavaFX - Failed to automatically set-up a JavaFX Platform

Tags: java, javafx

Estoy intentando crear un archivo JavaFx pero me da ese mensaje de error.

Lo que he hecho:

1. Ir a https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/
2. Extraje el .rar en el disco principal c://Java
3. Fui a netbeans y luego, tools y libraries, cree una carpeta que se llame JavaFx y exporte los 8 archivos que vienen en la carpeta "Lib" del SDK.
4. Cerré el netbeans y lo abri denuevo pero aún no me deja.

¿Alguien sabe que hacer aquí?

Saludos.
[image: Java]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en la misma página de gluon hay un plugin para  netbeans que descarga las dependencias a través de maven [plugin netbeans gluon](https://plugins.netbeans.apache.org/catalogue/?id=47)

Comment: dejé una respuesta en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/272542/c%c3%b3mo-importar-javafx-en-netbeans/528775#528775) para inicar un proyecto javafx con el plugin de netbeans